# Installing a linux OS on a usb drive without iso image from a CD/DVD!

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, usb-drive, iso

I was wandering if that's even possible! The other day my hdd crashed and it got me into thinking what if I could install a full OS on a usb (not live os though) from my cd/dvd that I had. So I fired up my pc without a hdd and with a kali-i386 cd along with my 4gb usb drive. Sadly the installation halted at the installation step which I assume is because of the 4gb size (it's not enough big). Apparently I don't have any plans on buying a new usb drive for now. So..is that possible!!! And have anyone actually tried it though!

Comment: When you say halted what do you mean? Some USB drives are very slow. You can find yourself waiting a long time.  Be aware that USB drives are likely to be less reliable than hard drives as their rewrite limit can be exceeded. USB sticks != SSD drive.

Comment: whats wrong with live system? you can set up casper-rw for persistence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use USB-attached storage as the main drive for a linux system.  a couple of months ago I installed debian on an 8G USB flash,  and I know of others that have used USB connected hard disks.